# How to include CSS.js in SenchaTouch CSS.swapStyleSheet

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How would like to include to include CSS.js in my Sencha Touch application. I need to use.
CSS.swapStyleSheet

Should I reference this file in app.js?

Thanks

Comment: You mean Ext.util.CSS from EXTJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the CSS.js file in app/util/ and edit your app.js like so:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
  'Ext': 'touch/src',
  ...
  'Ext.util.CSS': './app/util/CSS.js' <-- Add this line
});
```

Then require the util wherever you need it

```
require: [
  'Ext.util.CSS'
]
```

**Update**

To be safe and to avoid conflict, you should rename the util in case Sencha decide to actually  add `Ext.util.CSS` to the framework.

For instance, rename it `YOUR_APP.util.CSS`

Then you don't have to add anything to the `Ext.Loader.setPath()` and you would need to require `YOUR_APP.util.CSS`